# this.transitionToRoute doesn't work without params

Tags: javascript, ember.js, web-applications, routes

Good day StackOverflow,

```
// routes
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('myresource');
    this.resource('myresource', { path: 'myresource/:param1' });
});

// call transition from controller when switch not selected any params
// doesn't work...
this.transitionToRoute('myresource');
```

Need help, i want go to 'domain.tld/myresource' if not selected any params on view. But it's not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// router
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('myresource');
    this.route('anothermyresource', { path: 'myresource/: param1' });   
});

// router extend for another my resource
setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('myresource').setProperties({isNew:false, content:model});
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('myresource');         
    },
    model: function (params) {
        if (params.param1 === 'paramValue') return this.store.find('resource', {param1: 0});
    }

// and now work like as need
this.transitionToRoute('myresource');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should nest your routes like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('resources', {path: '/myresource', function() {
        this.route('resource', {path: '/myresource/:param1'});
    }); 
});
```

This should give you the URL routes you're requesting without the work around, plus clean up your Route/View/Controller/Component names.

Comment: Ok, how should see resource controller ? I want use one controller for /myresource and /myresource/:param1 -- this is filter for /myresource. Main controller is resources not resource

Comment: You could set the controllerName property on the route,but if this is just a filter, it'd be better to use a query parameters instead of a dynamic segment.

Comment: I know, but i want url like /myresource/value for filtering, because this url is clean than /myresource?param1=value

Comment: And what logic need to be realized in your choice, controller and template should be in 'resource' or 'resources', please show some example for this construction... i'm a newbie in Ember, and have many trouble with it... because so many information in internet and manuals on site that already deprecated ;)